# How to get the confidence interval after sum in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset, which is on an event basis, like below,

```
Young<- structure(list(Year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L), Month = c(10L, 10L, 
10L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L), Day = c(19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 9L, 9L, 9L), Hour = c("11:00:00", "12:00:00", 
"12:00:00", "16:00:00", "16:00:00", "16:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", 
"16:00:00", "13:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "13:00:00", "13:00:00", 
"14:00:00", "15:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "15:00:00", "15:00:00", 
"15:00:00", "16:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", 
"15:00:00", "16:00:00", "16:00:00", "16:00:00", "15:00:00", "15:00:00", 
"16:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "16:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", 
"15:00:00"), Treatment = c("Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control"), Age = c("Young", 
"Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
"Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
"Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
"Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
"Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", "Young", 
"Young", "Young", "Young"), Plot = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
4L), CutUncut = c("Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", 
"Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", 
"Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", 
"Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", 
"Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", 
"Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut", "Uncut"), DOY = c(293L, 
293L, 293L, 355L, 355L, 355L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 229L, 229L, 229L, 
263L, 263L, 263L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
128L, 128L, 128L, 164L, 164L, 164L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 207L, 207L, 
207L, 222L, 222L, 222L), Season = c("Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", 
"Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Summer", 
"Summer", "Summer", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Winter", "Winter", 
"Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", 
"Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", 
"Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", 
"Summer"), ParNEE = c(290.7248731, 599.7403381, 620.7083338, 
32.78885425, 62.01252568, 45.52391483, 1071.670139, 1093.367386, 
800.6788483, 419.0408238, 412.778134, 1327.117535, 839.7914373, 
644.0409088, 279.2245603, 191.8809568, 198.8807589, 140.3205729, 
467.648241, 165.6642216, 96.16016992, 762.2635568, 540.4431615, 
785.3492862, 1732.119114, 1129.006272, 1057.400471, 600.8070811, 
494.626709, 716.4676621, 874.3964178, 766.3067725, 722.804594, 
1841.223679, 1857.914923, 1851.643175, 1885.19335, 1874.080518, 
1886.155761), TsoilNEE = c(8.20641798, 8.87167614, 9.25483531, 
5.35562467, 5.001391598, 5.142751522, 5.447442626, 2.774806172, 
5.73145326, 16.39260095, 16.63689439, 16.00032251, 13.80826586, 
13.70293495, 14.05993565, -148.3114899, -125.1212398, -39.50172764, 
-0.153912547, 0.250569622, -0.180588761, 7.026564873, 6.613643378, 
6.750276902, 10.9441073, 9.815122309, 10.96556178, 13.72630399, 
13.91668339, 14.75620705, 16.07427164, 17.02269846, 15.89705194, 
17.48706912, 18.1624207, 17.27015855, 15.88739078, -313.4308453, 
-200.2484216), TairNEE = c(11.84885994, 12.25500113, 13.33651023, 
9.929997869, 9.802112232, 9.682167101, 22.46247535, 25.07250631, 
25.27596815, 27.62653943, 29.58273819, 29.58725575, 24.72666853, 
24.55716774, 20.72507946, 9.805187988, 9.747996729, 9.705873269, 
4.765671568, 3.773874476, 3.891349753, 20.38603849, 20.30943844, 
20.69971814, 22.20306747, 24.75430113, 24.77324059, 23.4390849, 
23.41247396, 23.06330721, 35.67870836, 34.35199338, 33.98895943, 
40.66750538, 37.41804298, 37.19870659, 29.66119092, 31.58723976, 
30.10279262), FluxNEE = c(-3.206353246, -4.163998348, -9.420162768, 
0.037262928, -1.336588509, -0.224057957, -0.508366229, -0.303823561, 
0.451989541, -4.629461578, -4.128336306, -19.31431488, -17.41555463, 
-10.76842377, -3.773743494, -4.005118396, -3.10139429, -3.896511575, 
-0.230811062, -0.387848425, 0.106525664, -2.093040652, -2.140873245, 
-3.342366374, -4.283554855, -3.90440069, -6.694529951, -10.79442231, 
-7.57943893, -8.668064652, -9.796745843, -9.068490841, -11.23867962, 
-2.881690108, -6.139469398, -11.55337646, -17.73289009, -11.81309017, 
-10.19259206), ParER = c(0.079582144, 0.078538246, 0.076666822, 
0.075928068, 0.071107485, 0.067917311, 0.079550601, 0.079545707, 
0.076062537, 0.066680977, 0.044227931, 0.064819571, 0.084869874, 
0.085468009, 0.073554044, 0.078895503, 0.070483716, 0.079795927, 
0.071635126, 0.074950603, 0.085683638, 0.067656389, 0.061385558, 
0.063857453, 0.071950763, 0.09015295, 0.077798096, 0.05698102, 
0.075428953, 0.048109063, 0.06919603, 0.068823704, 0.082922817, 
1843.888325, 1855.967312, 1856.078984, 1887.559762, 1877.441029, 
1881.282226), TsoilER = c(8.212540539, 8.913773301, 9.37379959, 
5.352583624, 5.003265737, 5.129246633, 3.585953441, 4.227443559, 
6.270562446, 16.35403573, 16.89910109, 15.72318925, 13.51008097, 
13.64622863, 14.01804184, -136.13081, -112.691455, -29.0108879, 
-0.250624887, 0.234876446, -0.192253951, 7.242462111, 6.581003774, 
7.304472456, 10.73760849, 9.970181595, 11.00729429, 13.62692044, 
13.94769746, 14.73160985, 16.18365114, 16.87261231, 15.8735923, 
17.35071047, 18.44087514, 16.87495921, 15.93538216, -217.3594646, 
18.1232224), TairER = c(11.52528319, 12.64744211, 13.63468403, 
9.899656846, 9.727256358, 9.639747971, 24.83383448, 25.18722803, 
25.49742845, 27.23686553, 28.59409676, 29.95920761, 24.58571143, 
24.69913034, 20.61829429, 9.669081306, 9.732249093, 9.544825508, 
5.041718517, 3.73260756, 3.753481235, 20.24927008, 20.38445081, 
21.03628444, 22.96717296, 23.93519561, 24.59680342, 23.274129, 
23.18265753, 23.30700413, 35.65016436, 34.33754475, 33.67091287, 
40.44720666, 37.56765173, 37.26631998, 29.50898978, 31.78674575, 
30.593999), FluxER = c(1.057273055, 1.131077804, 1.286326278, 
0.933058574, 1.162736073, 1.056358927, 2.210981831, 1.401988009, 
1.500512866, 5.052906165, 4.628101935, 6.530351267, 3.258632563, 
2.530428826, 2.847726462, 1.041944383, 0.591929214, 0.888592631, 
0.085761062, 0.137706908, 0.124532256, 1.102969996, 1.210864425, 
1.550348555, 1.981517329, 1.691527815, 3.072262372, 4.667099959, 
3.568560761, 3.798178884, 6.782221267, 5.772727381, 7.887602279, 
7.772539297, 7.873300514, 10.72683275, 8.24859913, 5.51910253, 
5.920298815), Photosynth = c(-4.263626301, -5.295076152, -10.706489046, 
-0.895795646, -2.499324582, -1.280416884, -2.71934806, -1.70581157, 
-1.048523325, -9.682367743, -8.756438241, -25.844666147, -20.674187193, 
-13.298852596, -6.621469956, -5.047062779, -3.693323504, -4.785104206, 
-0.316572124, -0.525555333, -0.018006592, -3.196010648, -3.35173767, 
-4.892714929, -6.265072184, -5.595928505, -9.766792323, -15.461522269, 
-11.147999691, -12.466243536, -16.57896711, -14.841218222, -19.126281899, 
-10.654229405, -14.012769912, -22.28020921, -25.98148922, -17.3321927, 
-16.112890875), DayNumber = c(4705L, 4705L, 4705L, 4767L, 4767L, 
4767L, 4500L, 4500L, 4500L, 4641L, 4641L, 4641L, 4675L, 4675L, 
4675L, 4802L, 4802L, 4802L, 4818L, 4818L, 4818L, 4858L, 4858L, 
4858L, 4906L, 4906L, 4906L, 4942L, 4942L, 4942L, 4958L, 4958L, 
4958L, 4985L, 4985L, 4985L, 5000L, 5000L, 5000L), Date = c("2011-10-19", 
"2011-10-19", "2011-10-19", "2011-12-20", "2011-12-20", "2011-12-20", 
"2011-03-28", "2011-03-28", "2011-03-28", "2011-08-16", "2011-08-16", 
"2011-08-16", "2011-09-19", "2011-09-19", "2011-09-19", "2012-01-24", 
"2012-01-24", "2012-01-24", "2012-02-09", "2012-02-09", "2012-02-09", 
"2012-03-20", "2012-03-20", "2012-03-20", "2012-05-07", "2012-05-07", 
"2012-05-07", "2012-06-12", "2012-06-12", "2012-06-12", "2012-06-28", 
"2012-06-28", "2012-06-28", "2012-07-25", "2012-07-25", "2012-07-25", 
"2012-08-09", "2012-08-09", "2012-08-09"), Location = c(19L, 
21L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 
21L, 21L, 19L, 20L, 19L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 21L, 20L, 
20L, 21L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 20L, 19L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 21L), 
    MossBiomass = c(0.81122449, 0.870408163, 0.532653061, 0.532653061, 
    0.81122449, 0.870408163, 0.532653061, 0.870408163, 0.81122449, 
    0.870408163, 0.81122449, 0.532653061, 0.532653061, 0.81122449, 
    0.870408163, 0.870408163, 0.81122449, 0.532653061, 0.81122449, 
    0.870408163, 0.532653061, 0.81122449, 0.870408163, 0.532653061, 
    0.81122449, 0.870408163, 0.532653061, 0.532653061, 0.870408163, 
    0.81122449, 0.870408163, 0.81122449, 0.532653061, 0.81122449, 
    0.870408163, 0.532653061, 0.532653061, 0.81122449, 0.870408163
    ), CallunaBiomass = c(0.730612245, 0.766326531, 0.774489796, 
    0.774489796, 0.730612245, 0.766326531, 0.774489796, 0.766326531, 
    0.730612245, 0.766326531, 0.730612245, 0.774489796, 0.774489796, 
    0.730612245, 0.766326531, 0.766326531, 0.730612245, 0.774489796, 
    0.730612245, 0.766326531, 0.774489796, 0.730612245, 0.766326531, 
    0.774489796, 0.730612245, 0.766326531, 0.774489796, 0.774489796, 
    0.766326531, 0.730612245, 0.766326531, 0.730612245, 0.774489796, 
    0.730612245, 0.766326531, 0.774489796, 0.774489796, 0.730612245, 
    0.766326531), TotalBiomass = c(1.541836735, 1.636734694, 
    1.307142857, 1.307142857, 1.541836735, 1.636734694, 1.307142857, 
    1.636734694, 1.541836735, 1.636734694, 1.541836735, 1.307142857, 
    1.307142857, 1.541836735, 1.636734694, 1.636734694, 1.541836735, 
    1.307142857, 1.541836735, 1.636734694, 1.307142857, 1.541836735, 
    1.636734694, 1.307142857, 1.541836735, 1.636734694, 1.307142857, 
    1.307142857, 1.636734694, 1.541836735, 1.636734694, 1.541836735, 
    1.307142857, 1.541836735, 1.636734694, 1.307142857, 1.307142857, 
    1.541836735, 1.636734694), Efflux = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), SM = c(0.284347997493598, 0.284347997493598, 
    0.284347997493598, 0.245463893974316, 0.245463893974316, 
    0.245463893974316, 0.222652267105158, 0.222652267105158, 
    0.222652267105158, 0.252836852714222, 0.252836852714222, 
    0.252836852714222, 0.278406340793348, 0.278406340793348, 
    0.278406340793348, 0.259937125926954, 0.259937125926954, 
    0.259937125926954, 0.232801146590399, 0.232801146590399, 
    0.232801146590399, 0.227096876335852, 0.227096876335852, 
    0.227096876335852, 0.229079210892252, 0.229079210892252, 
    0.229079210892252, 0.230726906942308, 0.230726906942308, 
    0.230726906942308, 0.232011241533852, 0.232011241533852, 
    0.232011241533852, 0.220105334847203, 0.220105334847203, 
    0.220105334847203, 0.236470079582821, 0.236470079582821, 
    0.236470079582821), SoilTemp = c(9.950000286, 10.04999971, 
    10.04999971, 4.700000048, 4.700000048, 4.700000048, NA, NA, 
    NA, 15.75, 15.75, 16.10000038, 13.3499999, 13.3499999, 13.54999971, 
    4.200000048, 4.200000048, 4.299999952, 0.100000001, 0.100000001, 
    0.100000001, 6.700000048, 6.700000048, 6.75, 9.950000286, 
    10.25, 10.25, 14.19999981, 14.19999981, 14.19999981, 16.44999981, 
    16.44999981, 16.65000057, 17.19999981, 17.5, 17.5, 16.64999962, 
    16.80000019, 16.80000019), RelHumid = c(0.88, 0.84, 0.84, 
    0.86, 0.86, 0.86, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.6, 0.6, 0.54, 0.76, 
    0.76, 0.75, 0.93, 0.93, 0.94, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.62, 0.62, 
    0.64, 0.45, 0.43, 0.43, 0.74, 0.74, 0.74, 0.63, 0.63, 0.64, 
    0.43, 0.46, 0.46, 0.58, 0.56, 0.56), AirTemp = c(8.9, 10.4, 
    10.4, 6.6, 6.6, 6.6, 9.4, 9.7, 9.7, 20.9, 20.9, 21.2, 16.1, 
    16.1, 16.2, 4.9, 4.9, 4.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 13.4, 13.4, 12.9, 
    14, 14.7, 14.7, 17.2, 17.2, 17.2, 26.8, 26.8, 26.9, 30.3, 
    29.8, 29.8, 21.6, 21.6, 21.6), Solar = c(166.6, 272.8, 272.8, 
    12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 221.6, 258.2, 258.2, 578.6, 578.6, 525.5, 
    364.4, 364.4, 309.4, 111.7, 111.7, 73.2, 144.7, 144.7, 144.7, 
    368, 368, 227.1, 767.2, 651.9, 651.9, 375.4, 375.4, 375.4, 
    446.8, 446.8, 391.8, 796.5, 730.6, 730.6, 269.2, 787.4, 787.4
    ), PAR = c(300.3, 503.5, 503.5, 14.6, 14.6, 14.6, 419.3, 
    479.7, 479.7, 1100.5, 1100.5, 996.1, 703.1, 703.1, 607.9, 
    194.1, 194.1, 120.8, 263.7, 263.7, 263.7, 714.1, 714.1, 428.5, 
    1433.7, 1192, 1192, 705, 705, 705, 869.8, 869.8, 750.7, 1536.3, 
    1411.7, 1411.7, 540.2, 1534.4, 1534.4)), row.names = c(11L, 
12L, 13L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 140L, 141L, 143L, 165L, 
166L, 168L, 206L, 208L, 210L, 227L, 228L, 231L, 254L, 256L, 258L, 
273L, 279L, 281L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 324L, 325L, 331L, 341L, 348L, 
349L, 365L, 372L, 373L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then I use these data to fit a model

```
GPPyoung = nls(-Photosynth ~ (ParNEE*(a*SoilTemp))/(ParNEE+Pk),  
               data = Young, 
               start=list(a = 0.1,Pk=100), lower=0.0001, algorithm='port')

AIC(GPPyoung)  # 201.99
coefficients(GPPyoung)  # 
summary(GPPyoung)# 
confint(GPPyoung) # to get the 95% confident intervals for the perameters.


# Compare the observed vs predicted
Pk = coefficients(GPPyoung)['Pk']
a = coefficients(GPPyoung)['a']
```

Based on these data, I got the results of parameters `Pk` and `a`. Then I use this model to fit another dataset `Meteo`, which is an hourly dataset, to get the hourly results of the `Photosynth`. Finally, I used the `sum()` function to get the annual value of `Photosynth`.

But now my question is how to calculate the confidence interval or the uncertainty of the annual value of `Photosynth`. Becuase it's just a sum value not an average value at all. But we really want to know the uncertainty of the whole model.

```
Meteo$GPPyoung <- (Meteo$PAR*(a*Meteo$SoilTemp))/(Meteo$PAR+Pk)

Meteo<- structure(list(Date = c("1/06/2010 0:00", "1/06/2010 1:00", "1/06/2010 2:00", 
"1/06/2010 3:00", "1/06/2010 4:00", "1/06/2010 5:00", "1/06/2010 6:00", 
"1/06/2010 7:00", "1/06/2010 8:00", "1/06/2010 9:00", "1/06/2010 10:00", 
"1/06/2010 11:00", "1/06/2010 12:00", "1/06/2010 13:00", "1/06/2010 14:00", 
"1/06/2010 15:00", "1/06/2010 16:00", "1/06/2010 17:00", "1/06/2010 18:00", 
"1/06/2010 19:00", "1/06/2010 20:00", "1/06/2010 21:00", "1/06/2010 22:00", 
"1/06/2010 23:00", "2/06/2010 0:00", "2/06/2010 1:00", "2/06/2010 2:00", 
"2/06/2010 3:00", "2/06/2010 4:00", "2/06/2010 5:00", "2/06/2010 6:00", 
"2/06/2010 7:00", "2/06/2010 8:00", "2/06/2010 9:00", "2/06/2010 10:00", 
"2/06/2010 11:00", "2/06/2010 12:00", "2/06/2010 13:00", "2/06/2010 14:00", 
"2/06/2010 15:00", "2/06/2010 16:00", "2/06/2010 17:00", "2/06/2010 18:00", 
"2/06/2010 19:00", "2/06/2010 20:00", "2/06/2010 21:00", "2/06/2010 22:00", 
"2/06/2010 23:00", "3/06/2010 0:00", "3/06/2010 1:00"), Year = c(2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L), Month = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Day = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), Hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L), RelHumid = c(0.95, 
0.96, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.98, 0.95, 0.82, 0.76, 
0.7, 0.67, 0.62, 0.63, 0.59, 0.64, 0.65, 0.69, 0.73, 0.78, 0.84, 
0.91, 0.94, 0.96, 0.96, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 0.98, 0.93, 0.73, 
0.65, 0.6, 0.52, 0.45, 0.42, 0.41, 0.42, 0.44, 0.46, 0.45, 0.43, 
0.49, 0.62, 0.78, 0.9, 0.94), AirTemp = c(6.7, 6.2, 5.3, 4.2, 
4, 3.4, 3.9, 5.7, 9.7, 11.6, 14, 15.2, 17.2, 18.2, 19.6, 19, 
19.7, 19.1, 18.6, 17.6, 16.6, 15.9, 14.3, 13.3, 11.2, 9.2, 6.9, 
5.7, 4.9, 4.1, 3.6, 6.9, 11.5, 14.7, 16.4, 18.3, 20.1, 21.4, 
22.1, 22.8, 22.8, 22.8, 22.3, 21.6, 20, 17.9, 14.9, 10.6, 7, 
5.8), Solar = c(1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 12.8, 86.1, 212.4, 
254.5, 375.4, 368, 629.9, 640.9, 705, 448.6, 465.1, 373.5, 234.4, 
166.6, 102.5, 53.1, 12.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 
14.6, 113.5, 238, 395.5, 529.2, 679.3, 792.8, 862.4, 884.4, 851.4, 
785.5, 699.5, 554.8, 390, 227.1, 87.9, 12.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8), 
   PAR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14.6, 155.6, 391.8, 485.2, 734.3, 
   721.4, 1259.8, 1292.7, 1422.7, 869.8, 917.4, 734.3, 454.1, 
   311.3, 184.9, 86.1, 12.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18.3, 197.8, 
   459.6, 791, 1073, 1355, 1618.7, 1759.6, 1779.8, 1730.3, 1571, 
   1386.1, 1080.3, 754.4, 448.6, 168.5, 22, 0, 0, 0), SoilTemp = c(10.23626137, 
   9.870399475, 9.595145226, 9.342157364, 9.180820465, 9.042314529, 
   9.019209862, 9.180820465, 9.549196243, 9.984869003, 10.41872025, 
   10.87355137, 11.3039856, 11.91307545, 12.81039906, 13.16781235, 
   13.3907938, 13.52444077, 13.25704098, 12.87747669, 12.56419373, 
   12.25024033, 11.9355793, 11.62017345, 11.23612499, 10.76001549, 
   10.28190517, 9.893303871, 9.61811161, 9.36518383, 9.203886032, 
   9.226944923, 9.572173119, 9.961985588, 10.32752895, 10.69184017, 
   11.19086361, 12.13794422, 13.3907938, 14.83355808, 16.04715157, 
   16.37726593, 15.95906639, 14.83355808, 13.90255451, 12.98920727, 
   12.3400116, 11.62017345, 10.94161892, 10.44150639), Hour1 = c("0:00:00", 
   "1:00:00", "2:00:00", "3:00:00", "4:00:00", "5:00:00", "6:00:00", 
   "7:00:00", "8:00:00", "9:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", 
   "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", 
   "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", "20:00:00", "21:00:00", 
   "22:00:00", "23:00:00", "0:00:00", "1:00:00", "2:00:00", 
   "3:00:00", "4:00:00", "5:00:00", "6:00:00", "7:00:00", "8:00:00", 
   "9:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", 
   "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", 
   "19:00:00", "20:00:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", "23:00:00", 
   "0:00:00", "1:00:00"), DayNumber = c(4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 
   4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 
   4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 4200, 
   4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 
   4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 
   4201, 4201, 4201, 4201, 4202, 4202), Measurement.Time = structure(list(
       sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 
       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
       4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
       16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
       4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
       16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L), mday = c(1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), mon = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
       5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
       5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
       5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
       5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), year = c(110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
       110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
       110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
       110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
       110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 
       110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L), 
       wday = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), yday = c(151L, 
       151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 
       151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 
       151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 
       152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 
       152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 152L, 
       152L, 152L, 153L, 153L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L), zone = c("CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
       "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
       "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
       "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
       "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
       "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
       "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
       "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
       NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
       NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
       NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
       NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
       NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
       NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
       NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
       NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
       NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
       NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("POSIXlt", 
   "POSIXt")), GPPyoung = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.590594499464422, 
   4.25789413130195, 7.13964983293584, 8.09364257311046, 9.59430060918616, 
   9.96591619422887, 11.703172902607, 12.3885249598014, 13.5318467495935, 
   12.6479996031782, 13.0198166013451, 12.4542695460619, 10.4923575609493, 
   8.71893654495587, 6.4730880637325, 3.76653362912719, 0.689650416319457, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.74554835122207, 4.94356227894899, 
   7.60948634247972, 9.35134022285773, 10.3784721078367, 11.2061336432827, 
   12.0500200644512, 13.2185959001941, 14.6046656499378, 16.1185068720173, 
   17.205706913021, 17.2282182581709, 16.0592648798236, 13.7569296564082, 
   10.9537918957097, 6.32934387849538, 1.1861821961113, 0, 0, 
   0)), row.names = 745:794, class = "data.frame")
```

```
Young <- sum((Meteo$GPPyoung* 60 * 60 * 12 * (1/1000000)), na.rm=TRUE)
```

My idea is: the parameters `Pk` and `a` follow the normal distribution, so maybe I can use a loop function for the model fit with a range of `Pk` and `a` and then got a range of results, which then I could choose the confidence intervals based on the results. Finally, sum up them to get the annual confidence interval?

I am not sure about this idea.

Comment: have you considered bootstrapping?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva I haven't tried it before, don't really have any idea about it. But I will give it a try.

Comment: bootstrapping is a way to estimate a sampling distribution (hence confidence interval or standard error) when calculating it analytically is difficult.  just checking, do you really want a confidence interval for the new dataset or a prediction interval?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Yep.

Comment: OK.  Your idea to resample from the distribution of Pk and a isn't bad but with 2 caveats, first they are likely correlated so sampling from both independently will be misleading, second they probably don't have normally distributed sampling distributions.  Bootstrapping would give you an empirical estimate of their actual joint sampling distribution.  If you add the code for the final part of your process (the summation) I can help with it.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Yep, Pk and a are somehow correlated. I have updated the sum code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding this as a partial solution with some caveats.  First is that I'm assuming your initial model is correct, that is the observations can be treated as independent of each other given the covariates and that the shape of the curve is appropriate.  If I was doing this for real I would think very hard about the resampling, that is whether I need to sample observations in clusters corresponding to the experimental design.

Second, the boostrapping doesn't always work, the model fails to converge for sometimes so you'll need find a way around this if you want to run a reasonable number of boostrap replicates.

You can use bootstrapping to estimate the confidence interval for the sum you requested as follows.  I'm using `predict` to get the fitted values for the new data, and so I need to make the `Meteo` dataframe have predictor names that correspond to the names in the model.  Then I use `boot` to estimate the confidence interval.

When I ran the bootstrap just to get the CIs for the model coefficients they were very close to the CIs reported by running `confint` on the original model so it seems to work OK.  That also suggests it might be OK to resample the coefficients from the joint distribution of the estimates (you can get the covariance from `vcov(GPPyoung)` so maybe the boostrapping isn't the best way!

```
Meteo$ParNEE <-Meteo$PAR
getEstimates <- function(dat, w){
  GPPyoung = nls(-Photosynth ~ (ParNEE*(a*SoilTemp))/(ParNEE+Pk),  
               data = dat[w,], 
               start=list(a = 0.1,Pk=100), lower=0.0001, algorithm='port')
  sum((predict(GPPyoung, newdata = Meteo)* 60 * 60 * 12 * (1/1000000)), na.rm=TRUE)  
}

library(boot)
b1 <- boot(Young, getEstimates, 100)
b1
boot.ci(b1)


> b1

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = Young, statistic = getEstimates, R = 100)


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original    bias    std. error
t1* 14.19008 0.1035427   0.9388517
> boot.ci(b1)
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 100 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = b1)

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   (12.25, 15.93 )   (11.71, 15.98 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   (12.40, 16.67 )   (12.38, 16.46 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
Some basic intervals may be unstable
Some percentile intervals may be unstable
Some BCa intervals may be unstable
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't really understand why here use ```data = dat[w,], ```? And this way seems like doesn't work in my another dataset, which gives the warning message like ```Error in nls(-Photosynth ~ (ParNEE * (a * SoilTemp))/(ParNEE + Pk), data = dat[w,  : 
  Convergence failure: false convergence (8)```

Comment: The convergence issue I mentioned in the answer, it doesn't always work.  dat[w,] is how the bootstrap resamples for each iteration are selected, look at the help for `boot`.  Like I said, I'm not sure this is the best answer, but I thought I'd post it since it might be a helpful starting point or helpful to others with similar problem.